# Pydantic validation error field required in FastAPI while using environments

Tags: python, fastapi, environment, pydantic

I was following a Python API development course on FreeCodeCamp on YouTube where we moved some static values to environment variables. This is the error I got while trying to reload the app:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 8 validation errors for Settings
database_hostname
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
database_port
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
database_password
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
database_name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
database_username
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
secret_key
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
algorithm
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
access_token_expire_minutes
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

> Here's my schema (config.py):

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    database_hostname: str
    database_port: str
    database_password: str
    database_name: str
    database_username: str
    secret_key: str
    algorithm: str
    access_token_expire_minutes: int

    class Config:
        env_file = '../.env'
```

> Here's my environment (.env):

```
DATABASE_HOSTNAME=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
DATABASE_NAME=fastapi
DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
SECRET_KEY=123456789
ALGORITHM=HS256
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=60
```

How do I make my BaseSettings class able to read the environment variables in the .env file?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve the error by using a full path in the project. I've got the main project folder and within that the `.env` file and an `app` folder. My config.py file is in `app/` so the relative path to the env file from config is `/../.env`:

> Don't forget to import os

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    database_hostname: str
    database_port: str
    database_password: str
    database_name: str
    database_username: str
    secret_key: str
    algorithm: str
    access_token_expire_minutes: int

    class Config:
        env_file = f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))}/../.env"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

if .env file is the same folder as your main app folder.

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    database_hostname: str
    database_port: str
    database_password: str
    database_name: str
    database_username: str
    secret_key: str
    algorithm: str
    access_token_expire_minutes: int

    class Config:
        env_file = '.env'
```